# Port Mirroring to another localhost port

Tags: networking

I have an application a running on Port Y (UDP). Is it possible to create a mirror without touching application A to receive the message in application a and additionally in application B (same host) on a different port Y?

I tried with

```
socat udp-listen:x,reuseaddr,fork udp:localhost:y
```

Unfortunately, `socat` starts a listener on port X and applicaton a does not receive the message.

I also read some solution with `iptables` with mangle - which does not seem to be supported by my `iptables` version anymore.

It needs to run on 2 different platforms:

- Ubuntu 20.04 with iptables v1.8.4 (legacy)
- SLES12SP5 with v1.4.21

I can not use a 2nd IP address in the subnet of my `eth0` interface.

Comment: I am not going to post my off the cuff answer, as I can not test right now, but I think you can do this with ssh port forwarding. I know

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you can do this [with IPtables](https://superuser.com/questions/1289166/mirror-all-traffic-from-one-port-to-another-on-localhost-using-iptables)...

From that site:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p UDP --dport 162 -j TEE --gateway 127.0.0.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.2 -p UDP --dport 162 -j DNAT  --to 127.0.0.1:1162
```

Read more about it on the site I linked.